# Opposite/Negation of phrases

Tags: antonyms

How is the opposite of compound phrases of the form "adjective noun" constructed?
Is "opposite of [adjective] [noun]" the same as "[opposite of adjective] [opposite of noun]", the same as "[adjective] [opposite of noun]" or the same as "[opposite of adjective] [noun]".

E.g., what the opposite of "short woman"? "short man", "tall woman" or "tall man"?

Comment: It depends on the speaker/writer's intent; it's not well-defined in general. As an analogy, consider the question of how an image's reflection looks - it depends on where the mirror is placed (e.g. above, below, side, front, etc).

Comment: Of course I'm only interested in the case where both words have an opposite and it is clear which opposite is meant, if one word has several.

Comment: They are not 'compounds' since they do not form a new noun. "Short" and "tall" are simply optional modifiers of nouns. The opposite of "short man" is "tall man" because of the adjectival modifier of opposite meaning.

Comment: @Brezel Yes, that's assumed. Each of your three suggestions is a valid *opposite*.

Comment: I've always maintained that the true opposite, including switching polarity, renders nearly the same. In this case, '(is a) short woman'  becomes '(isn't   multiple) tall men'. Of course, this is my somewhat humorous answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you clarify [in comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323010/opposite-negation-of-phrases?noredirect=1#comment734886_323010), we'll assume that all candidate negations have been determined.

Syntactically, if you negate an *adjective-noun* phrase, [@BillJ's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323010/opposite-negation-of-phrases?noredirect=1#comment734888_323010) makes sense: negate the adjective. So the opposite of *short* woman is *tall* woman. This becomes problematic when you have multiple adjectives - e.g. *tall, famous woman*, where your question repeats with respect to the multiple adjectives. If we want the (unique) *semantic* opposite to a phrase, we need more information.

To derive an *opposite* or *negation*, you need to specify what **quality** is being opposed or negated.

Here are some examples:

- take one of the ideas in [@Deonyi's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323010/opposite-negation-of-phrases?noredirect=1#comment734891_323010): if the quality is *plurality* (singular vs plural), then the opposite of *short woman* is *short women*;
- if the quality is the *adjective*, then the opposite of *short woman* is *tall* woman;
- if the quality is *gender*, then the opposite of *short woman* is *short man*; and
- if the quality is *age* (adult vs child), then the opposite of *short woman* is *short girl*, etc.

Once you specify the quality being negated, whether explicitly or via the context, the negation follows immediately. Without that specification, there are no grounds on which to judge *any* candidate negation correct.